# Spring Boot SessionFactory instantiation failed but only when containerised

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, neo4j

I have containerised a spring boot application. It is contained in a jar file. when I call the jar file separately ***It is working*** but when I run it through `docker-compose up` it yields the following error:

> ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'crawlerController': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'campaignservice'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'campaignService': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'campaignrepository'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'campaignRepository': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean
>   'org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SharedSessionCreator#0'
>   while setting bean property 'session'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SharedSessionCreator#0':
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting
>   constructor argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/neo4j/Neo4jDataAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory]: Factory method
>   'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javafx.util.Pair not present

Given that the jar works when invoked separately I assume that all of the dependencies are contained in the classpath. so I do not understand why it does not work when called through Docker

the dockerFile is :

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre

VOLUME /tmp
ADD target/SpringNeoServer.jar /SpringNeoServer.jar

EXPOSE 7864

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "SpringNeoServer.jar"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX is not included in this version of openjdk.

Instructions to add it can be found [here](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/issues/158).

Comment: I just found the answer as you sent it! https://gist.github.com/androidfred/bc64da9e6a355b984d37439ed63ae16b FOR FUTURE REFERENCE